# JAVA_HOME is empty and PATH is default inside the screen/script

Tags: java, linux, bash, java-home

I installed java 18 using this tutorial: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-oracle-java-18-on-ubuntu-debian/
Scripts (.sh) running at reboot from crontab doesn't have any JAVA_HOME and default PATH variables. When I run these scripts manually it works. After rebooting it's the same.

Comment: Why didn't you just install the openjdk with apt?

Comment: This is 100% normal/expected/intended/usual/as-documented behavior. Why do you expect anything different? Show us how you tried to _change_ the PATH used by cron and how it didn't work, and then there might be a question here.

Comment: Also, note that enough information to make a question answerable needs to be included *inside the body text of the question itself*, not behind a link. We're building a knowledge base here, and it needs to remain useful even if links break.

Comment: It works on my other machine. I didn't think about installing with apt and I don't know if java 18 is there. I tried adding it to bash_profile or similar, but it didn't help.